# Getting history data from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `History` table in a SQL Server database that I need to get information from different months for example I have an `EmployeeHistory` table, this table has a record for any update that I'm doing for each employee. During a month I can have many updates but I only only the latest one. I for example I don't do any update during a month, I show go I get the latest update for that month.

For example

```
ID Name Email           Date
1  A    a@hotmail.com   2013-01-10
1  A    new@hotmail.com 2013-01-20
1  A    n1@hotmail.com  2013-03-15
```

In this case I don't have any changes in February but I need to bring it with the same data as January, in this case the latest one from January should be repeated in February so the query should bring this result:

```
ID Name Email           Date
1  A    new@hotmail.com 2013-01-20
1  A    new@hotmail.com 2013-01-20
1  A    n1@hotmail.com  2013-03-15
```

How can I build the query for these cases?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a sequence of the months you can either use system table master..spt_values or your own sequence table. So you can find the values ​​for all months, regardless whether there are changes or not

```
SELECT DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(mm, v.number-1, '20010101')) AS mName, 
       o.Id, o.Email, o.[Date]
FROM master..spt_values v
  OUTER APPLY(
              SELECT h3.Id, h3.NAME, h3.Email, h3.Date 
              FROM (
                    SELECT h.Id, MAX(h.[Date]) AS [Date]
                    FROM dbo.EmployeeHistory h
                    WHERE MONTH(h.[Date]) <= v.number
                    GROUP BY h.Id
                    ) h2 JOIN dbo.EmployeeHistory h3
                      ON h2.Id = h3.Id AND h2.Date = h3.Date
              ) o
WHERE v.[type] = 'P' AND v.number BETWEEN 1 AND 12
```

For better performance, you can use this indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX x ON dbo.EmployeeHistory(Id, [Date]) INCLUDE(Name, Email)
```

[image]

See demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/13d4e/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

Start by creating a table variable that specifies the months for which you want to see the most recent history record for.

```
DECLARE @MonthsOfInterest AS TABLE (FirstOfMonth DATE)
```

Next, determine what dates you want to report on. You could hard-code the dates here like so:

```
INSERT INTO @MonthsOfInterest ( FirstOfMonth ) VALUES('2013-08-01')
INSERT INTO @MonthsOfInterest ( FirstOfMonth ) VALUES('2013-07-01')
INSERT INTO @MonthsOfInterest ( FirstOfMonth ) VALUES('2013-06-01')
...
```

Or you could be more suave and programmatically load in the past 12 months, or whatever.

But once you have this table variable created and populated you're off to the races. Now it's just a matter of a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT FirstOfMonth, Email, Date
FROM @MonthsOfInterest
    LEFT JOIN HistoryTable ON
        HistoryTable.ID = (
            SELECT TOP 1 ID 
            FROM HistoryTable 
            WHERE Date < @MonthsOfInterest.FirstOfMonth 
            ORDER BY Date DESC
        )
```

In English, for each record in `@MonthsOfInterest` we join on the `HistoryTable` record whose `Date` value is less than the start of the month *and* who has the largest `Date` value.

(Note: If there are multiple records with the same `Date` value it will choose the one that has the least `ID` value most likely. You could add an additional column to the `ORDER BY` clause if you wanted to break ties some other way.)

Thanks

Comment: I was checking but it doesn't work when I add another ID, for example 2

Comment: I was (perhaps incorrectly) presuming that `ID` is a primary key for the `HistoryTable` - is that not correct? Do you have a column that uniquely identifies every row in `HistoryTable`?

Comment: yes sorry for not mention it, I have an identity column plus the ID, in this case the ID of the employee that can be repeated.

Comment: Simply replace the `ID` reference in the `WHERE` clause (the two of them) with the name of your primary key column and it should work as expected.